# Translate JavaScript enter and exit methods into Python

Tags: javascript, python, compiler-construction, translate

I'm trying to translate The Super Tiny Compiler by James Kyle from JavaScript into Python.

But I'm having trouble understanding what the enter and exit methods from JavaScript do:

1)

```
// If there is an `enter` method for this node type we'll call it with the
// `node` and its `parent`.
if (methods && methods.enter) {
  methods.enter(node, parent);
}
```

2)

```
// If there is an `exit` method for this node type we'll call it with the
// `node` and its `parent`.
if (methods && methods.exit) {
  methods.exit(node, parent);
}
```

How can I translate these two methods in to Python?
Thank you.

[Here's a link to the Tiny Compiler code](https://the-super-tiny-compiler.glitch.me/traverser)

Comment: To understand what they do, I'd suggest reading more about The Super Tiny Compiler and looking at how `enter` and `exit` are defined. As for translating to Python, they're just methods which take two nodes. As long as you can write methods in Python, it's trivial to translate them.

Comment: I don't think enter and exit are defined in the Super Tiny Compiler.  I believe they are from the D3 JavaScript Library.

Comment: @MarcoLugo Why would D3 define visitors that can be applied to the AST? D3 is a data visualization library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find out it in the next file "4-tranformer.js". `enter` and `exit` are just methods of an object `methods` in `visitor`. Pay attention to this peace of code:

```
// We start by testing for the existence of a method on the visitor with a
// matching `type`.
let methods = visitor[node.type];
```

In the code you posted we just check if the `methods` object has a method `exit` or `enter` and call them if it does.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that the traverser was called specifically in the transformer.